# SailsJS: can not create Model in beforeCreate

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I use SailsJS (v0.12.3) and i want to create a User before it's profile created. My problem is the User is created successfully, but the UserProfile did not.

This is my `UserProfile` model:

```
beforeCreate: function (userProfile, cb) {
    // Creating user login
    console.log("Creating user login: ", userProfile);
    User.create({
        username: "abc",
        password: "1234567890"
    }).then(function (user) {
        console.log("Creating user done: ", user)
        userProfile.appUser = user.id;
        userProfile.code = user.username;
        cb(null, userProfile);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log("ABC", err);
        cb(err);
    });
}
```

The console output:

```
Creating user login:  { firstName: 'Vu',
  lastName: 'Bao',
  gender: 1,
  phoneNumber: '0987654321',
  id: '29b1b37b-ca95-4fd0-8cf8-e35a25af4616',
  code: '1469529082587',
  isVerified: false,
  totalVisit: 0 }
```

I can see message `Creating user login ...` is printed, but i can not see the log message `Creating user done ...` and `ABC` error.

The result: in database i got the `user` created but `userProfile` did not.

How can i create User model before UserProfile create correctly ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a while read about Model actions [Lifecycle callbacks](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks). I find my code did not call back function `afterCreate`that i defined in the `User` model. So, i do remove the function `afterCreate`, then it works.

```
// ./api/models/User.js
afterCreate: function (user, cb) {
    // i commented a lots in this function, but did not callback cb
    // then i remove this method because I did not need it anymore
    // ...
}
```

Thank for reading. Hope this help others !!

Comment: Ensure you will call back if you use lifecycle callbacks.